# Writing Gzip Files in AWS Lambda Boto3

Tags: python, amazon-s3, gzip, zlib

I'm using Boto3 on AWS Lambda to process a datastream and publish the contents to a file in s3 for downstream processing. The data can be simple raw json in this case.

I would like to use the `zlib` to store compressed gzip data to S3. In theory this is simple. However when I upload a gzip file using the following, my local machine says that the file is not in gzip format.

Can someone help explain what is going on here? This should be trivial. For what it is worth, when I read gzipped files that other programs produced, `zlib.decompress` requires `, 16+zlib.MAX_WBITS` as a `wbits` argument in order to correctly read the compressed string. Perhaps I need the `zlib.compress` equivalent?

```
import json
import zlib
import boto3
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    ## Sample dataset
   data = [{"var":1, "foo": "bar"}, {"var":2, "foo":"baz"}]
   payload = '\n'.join([json.dumps(r) for r in data]).encode('utf-8')

    ## Upload
    output = s3.Object("bucket", "file")
    output.put(Body=zlib.compress(payload))

    ## Download and verify
    obj = s3.Object("bucket", "file")

    ## Load the Streaming object body, decompress, decode
    # , 16+zlib.MAX_WBITS
    decompressed = zlib.decompress(obj.get()['Body'].read(), 16+zlib.MAX_WBITS).decode('utf-8').split("\n")
    print(f"Decompressed payload: {payload}")
    data2 = [json.loads(r) for r in decompressed]

    return {
        "statusCode": 200,
        "TestVerification?": data2==data,
        "body": json.dumps('Demo')
    }
```

Later, download the file locally:

```
zcat testcompressed.gz

gzip: testcompressed.gz: not in gzip format
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you'd need the `zlib.compress` equivalent. However, there isn't one. You instead need to use `zlib.compressobj`, which has a `wbits` parameter.

Comment: Spot on, this worked:


`compressor = zlib.compressobj(9, zlib.DEFLATED, zlib.MAX_WBITS | 16)
compressed = compressor.compress("This is a test1234".encode('utf-8')) + compressor.flush()`